# Returning a subset of related model data in Laravel/Eloquent

Tags: php, laravel-4, eloquent

I'm sure there's a way of doing this but it's defeated various of my approaches so far.

I have an Event model which belongsToMany artists like so:

```
public function artists() {

    return $this->belongsToMany('Artist', 'artists_events', 'event_id');

}
```

I can do this kind of business in the route:

```
    $events = Event::with('artists')->nearest()->future()->take(10)->get();
```

and then work out the artist names in the view:

```
@foreach($events as $event)

   <?php $artists = array();
     foreach ($event->artists as $artist):
         $artists[] = $artist->name;
     endforeach ?>
  <li>
        <a href="#">
            <span class="artist">{{ implode(',', $artists) }}</span> ...
```

But this seems hugely inelegant.  What I really want to do is generate and return `$event->artists` inside the Event model.  Any tips?  Getters and setters seem like a probable way forward, but I'm having a bit of trouble wrapping my head around how they would interact with the belongsToMany relationship.

Comment: It's unclear what you really want, so just a guess: `$event->artists->implode('name', ',');` it will do all you have in that view.

Comment: Thanks deczo, that seems to be exactly what I was looking for!  I didn't know you could do that, hence all my foolish attempts to return something different from the model.

Comment: Check the source code of `Support\Collection` and `Eloquent\Collection` - you will find many really helpful methods there.